# How do I add a mean line to each panel is a facet_grid() object?

Tags: r, facet-grid

I have a sample dataset here:

```
data = data.frame(Region = c(rep("Upper",50), rep("Lower", 50)),
                  Weight = c(rnorm(50, 2, 1), rnorm(50, 4, 1)))
```

I want to create a histogram in ggplot which the mean of each histogram overlaid with a red line.

```
ggplot(data=data, aes(x=Weight))+geom_histogram()+geom_vline(xintercept=mean(Weight), col="red")+facet_grid(Region~.)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Group your `data` by `Region` an calculate the mean for each respective `Weight`.

```
data <- data %>% group_by(Region) %>%  mutate(mean = mean(Weight))

ggplot(data, aes(x = Weight)) +
  geom_histogram() +
  facet_grid(Region~.) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = mean, group = Region), colour = 'red')
```

[image]

Comment: I found this is useful! I have a follow up question, how to use geom_text() in this case to display the median value for each histogram.